# IPV4 supportive mail function in linux

Tags: linux, email, postfix, sendmail, mailx

I'm working on a linux machine where changes are not allowed. But While I use sendmail function I'm getting following error.

```
sendmail: warning: inet_protocols: IPv6 support is disabled: Address family not supported by protocol
sendmail: warning: inet_protocols: configuring for IPv4 support only
postdrop: warning: inet_protocols: IPv6 support is disabled: Address family not supported by protocol
postdrop: warning: inet_protocols: configuring for IPv4 support only
postdrop: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to use mail function which is ip4 supportive? Not only the error come. It is not even sending the mail out.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that postdrop does not supports IPv4, it is that it is expecting also IPv6.

The machine is obviously using `postfix` as a mailer daemon.  If the sysadmin has disabled IPv6, postfix should give an warning at least each time it is restarted. Furthermore, if your sysadmin disables IPv6, he ought to finish the job and disable IPv6 support in some of the daemons that require it explicitly, like postfix.

To make the warning go away, I do advise to ask the sysadmin to add to `/etc/postfix/main.cf` the line:

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
```

What can be done at the application level, is that instead of using a function that supports the sendmail API, you can send email via TCP (to the same or another local email server).

Answer (score 0):

The messages you are seeing are explicitly saying that IPv4 *is* (indeed, is the *only*) supported protocol.  So, yes, and you currently are using a utility which supports IPv4.

Comment: What is IPV4 supportive mail function?

Comment: Based on the context of the question, a mail utility that supports the IPv4 protocol.